# Font used on Stripe.com?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone help me to identify the font used for most of the headings and body text on www.stripe.com

I am hoping it's a font which is available via Typekit or Google Fonts!

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [**Whitney SSm A**](http://www.typography.com/fonts/whitney/overview/), you can find it by using a CSS/HTML inspector:

```
font-family: 'Whitney SSm A','Whitney SSm B',Helvetica,Arial;
```

It's available as a **web font** through [Cloud Typography](http://www.typography.com/cloud/welcome/).

Comment: Is there any way to obtain this font with paying $99/year? That is a steep price.

Comment: @timpeterson I know this is old, but you can buy the OTF font. Looks like it's going for $199 with a bunch of variants.